# Where to find resource adapter for weblogic JMS?

Tags: resources, weblogic, wildfly-8

I would like to configure Wildfly to send JMS messages to Weblogic 12c. for this I am using jms bridge in wildfly and want to configure resource adapters.

Unfortunately I am not able to find required rar file of weblogic. Also I am looking for `module.xml` for this rar file.

Answer (score 0):

you may find your answer in the following references -

http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E24329_01/web.1211/e24378/basics.htm#SACLT117

Oracle resource adapters are located at WL_HOME\server\lib

http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E24329_01/web.1211/e24375/basics.htm#BRDGE128

Yes Searching for the jms jar file (wljmsra.jar) provided by weblogic I found the following -

```
/opt/oracle/middleware12c/wlserver/modules/com.bea.core.jmspool_3.0.0.0.jar
/opt/oracle/middleware12c/wlserver/modules/com.bea.web.pubsub.jms.ja_4.0.0.0.jar
/opt/oracle/middleware12c/wlserver/modules/com.bea.core.jmspool.ja_3.0.0.0.jar
/opt/oracle/middleware12c/wlserver/modules/com.bea.web.pubsub.jms_4.0.0.0.jar
/opt/oracle/middleware12c/wlserver/server/lib/jms-xa-adp/jmsadapter.jar
/opt/oracle/middleware12c/wlserver/server/lib/jms-local-adp/jmsadapter.jar
/opt/oracle/middleware12c/wlserver/server/lib/wlt3jmsclient-classesextra.jar
/opt/oracle/middleware12c/wlserver/server/lib/jms-notran-adp/jmsadapter.jar
/opt/oracle/middleware12c/wlserver/server/lib/console-ext/autodeploy/core-jms.jar
/opt/oracle/middleware12c/wlserver/server/lib/wljmsclient.jar
/opt/oracle/middleware12c/inventory/featuresets/resources/modules/wls_jmsClient_12.1.3.0.0.jar
/opt/oracle/middleware12c/oracle_common/modules/javax.jms_1.1.4.jar
/opt/oracle/middleware12c/oracle_common/common/templates/wls/oracle.wls-webservice-soapjms-template_12.1.3.jar
/opt/oracle/wlsdomains/domains/Wls1213/servers/AdminServer/tmp/_WL_internal/consoleapp/jxhze9/console-ext/core-jms/WEB-INF/lib/core-jms.jar
```

however http://docs.oracle.com/middleware/1212/wls/JMSRA/basics.htm#JMSRA117 clearly states

" Location of the JMS RA in the WebLogic Server Distribution

The wljmsra.jar file is located in the WL_HOME\server\lib directory of your WebLogic Server installation. "

Hence you should raise a support ticket with oracle to provide this file.

Comment: Thanks. I have gone through most of the links on Oracle including above and they all discuss about configuring other resource adapters inside Weblogic. I am looking for similar documentation for Wildfly. Something similar to this [link]http://blog.c2b2.co.uk/2014/01/connecting-jboss-wildfly-7-to-activemq.html . I could make out that there is a file named wljmsra.jar as per [link] docs.oracle.com/middleware/1212/wls/JMSRA/basics.htm#JMSRA117 but I could not find it.

Comment: Scratching about in a 12c installation, it looks like there's a typo in the Oracle documentation, I think it's intending to refer to wljmsra.rar not jar which is in the location specified.

Comment: @SridharS  Thanks for your support. Although I could not get rar file I managed to make it working by using wljmsclient.jar and wlthint3client.jar. I will post the complete solution for benefit of others.

Comment: Hey I realize this is old but was the full solution as stated ever posted?  I couldn't find it.